# how to communicate with tor network

Tags: delphi, indy

How can I communicate with Tor network in Delphi?

I want to use tor network for my IDHTTP1 operations

Is it possible?

If so, can any one help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tor is a SOCKS proxy, so you should be able to follow the [SOCKS answer from the INDY Faq](http://www.indyproject.org/KB/index.html?tidtcpclientsocks.htm):

indy 10:

1. Create an `IOHandler` such as `TIdIOHandlerStack` or SSL `IOHandler` and assign the `TCPClient.IOHandler` property this.
2. Create a `TIdSocksInfo` object and assign it to the `IOHandler`'s `TransparentProxy` property.
3. Set the `TIdSocksInfo` properties as required.
4. If there is another proxy that the SOCKS Proxy itself needs to use, you have to use, set the Chained Proxy to a `TIdCustomTransparentProxy` such as `TIdSocksInfo` for another socks Proxy or a `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy` for a HTTP Tunneling proxy.